# unable to access external IP from LAN

Tags: nat, lxc, ovh, proxmox

I have a server within OVH network. Proxmox 4.3 was installed there as a supervisor and it's hosting 2 LXC containters. Both are running in **192.168.11.0/24** network setup on vmbr2 network for which I have also setup NAT like that:

```
auto vmbr2
iface vmbr2 inet static
        address 192.168.11.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        bridge_ports none
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
        post-up iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '192.168.11.0/24' -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE
        post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '192.168.11.0/24' -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE
```

I've also bought Failover IP from OVH, setup virtual MAC for it and assigned it to one LXC container (vmbr0 interface).

My problem is that I can access this IP on LXC server where this IP is assigned (obviously), but I can't do that from other LXC server. Connection just timeout when I simply do wget to it.

What am I missing in my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I found it. Apparently I missed routing entry on main host:

```
route add -host failover_ip gw main_ip
```

Thanks to this all LXC hosts have now access to my Failover IP.